# Get child components to talk to eachother

Tags: reactjs

I know this has been asked before however I've been playing around with this for awhile and I'm not getting it. I have two child components being used and connected by parent `page`. The first child component is a form and the second child component is a table containing a list of all the userProfiles. When I submit the form, I wand to tell the table component to run a function. How do I do this?

Path: `Parent Component`

```
export default class StudentPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <AddStudentForm
          guardianUserProfiles={this.props.guardianUserProfiles}
        />
        <StudentTable
          studentUserProfiles={this.props.studentUserProfiles}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Path: `AddStudentForm`

```
export default class AddStudentForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    };

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="mb-3">
        <Input
          type="text"
          name="firstName"
          value={this.state.firstName}
          onChange={this.handleInputChange}
          id="firstName"
          placeholder="First name"
        />
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
      </Form>
    );
  }
}
```

Path: `StudentTable`

```
export default class StudentTable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    };

    this.handleTableUpdate = this.handleTableUpdate.bind(this);
  }

  handleTableUpdate = () => (event) => {
    // Do stuff
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Table hover bordered responsive>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th className="border-left border-top-0 border-right-0 pt-0">#</th>
              <th className="border-left-0 border-top-0 border-right-0 pt-0">First name</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {this.state.userProfile.map((studentUserProfile, idx) => (
              <tr>
                <React.Fragment>
                  <th rowSpan={studentUserProfile.classes.length} className="border-left aling-double-row">{idx + 1}</th>
                  <td rowSpan={studentUserProfile.classes.length} className="aling-double-row">{studentUserProfile.firstName}</td>
                </React.Fragment>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </Table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Make the state to be in parent component and pass it to child. So for example you want to run a function after the form has been submitted. You could in parent component create submitFunction that is passed to form component, so now when you submitted function from parent component you can pass new values to table component which are rendered and now in table component you can fire your required action.  Read more here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45950097/react-component-parent-child-interaction-component-lifecycle

Comment: Usually I would get the child component to talk to the parents first then go back to child. So parent > child  > parent > child 2.

Comment: @JunBin Could you show me an explicit example here. That's what I'm try to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Way 1:**
You can achieve this either by using flux or redux

**Way 2:**
You can send a call back form child1(ie page with form) to parent and send it as a prop from parent to child2(ie page with table).